# How to validate uploaded file contents?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Create action that takes an entity object and a HttpPostedFileBase csv file.

I can save the entity object in the database and the file in disk, but I am not sure how to validate the contents of the file.

for example,
~the file should have some basic information, name, id, email... (separated by ;)
~the field cannot be null
~the record must be an existing record (means, the record have references in the database)

Comment: Is this MVC or WebForms?

Comment: You'll just have to read in the file and do the checks.

Comment: @UweKeim it is a MVC. I would prefer you all give me some examples ^^ sorry im new to this...

Comment: @Crowcoder can you show me some examples of read?